# Keyboard backlight not working Clevo P170SM

Tags: shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I cant figure out how to turn on the keyboard backlight. I've been doing google searches for a couple days and haven't found a solution that worked for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Keypad /</kbd>? That shortcut should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem. I upgraded kernel 4.19 and install/activate lightdm , random freeze is stopped + keyboard backlight now work.